# Mean ±SE in scatterplot of three groups

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, tidyverse, rlang

**edit: It's occurred to me that standard error cannot / will not be computed by R for the non-HG species (in particular, GB) where n is rather small (n = 4 for GB).  Even if this is not the case for my failure to produce the plots, this low n is likely to invalidate standard error calculations. I'd appreciate others' advice.**

I've seen a few similar answers, but nothing that closely approximates to what I want to do.
I've successfully used the code located here - 
https://community.rstudio.com/t/using-stat-instead-of-dplyr-to-summarize-groups-in-a-ggplot/13916/2
- to produce a biplot showing the mean +/- s.e. whiskers for two groups of samples.

However, I've not been successful in re-working this code for use when there are three groups of samples. Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong and how to rectify it please?

Thank you very much indeed in advance for advice; much appreciated :-)

Sample data and code (below):

```
Species d13C lin    d34S lin
GB  -20.1   8.09
HG  -20.1   8.09
HG  -19.51  9.46
HG  -17.55  16.81
HG  -23.72  8.03
HG  -23.79  9.02
HG  -18.09  8.64
HG  -21.98  10.95
HG  -18.6   8.5
HG  -22.75  10.9
HG  -21.7   9.08
HG  -25 7.23
HG  -17.61  16.56
HG  -20.5   10.17
HG  -18.14  15.4
GB  -22.01  15.78
GB  -19.62  12.62
LB  -21.69  14.96
LB  -25.56  8.4
LB  -23.43  13.61
LB  -22.92  12.68
LB  -23.81  15.47
LB  -25.42  8.63
HG  -26.11  14.15
HG  -20.61  9.27
HG  -19.18  15.67
HG  -19.76  14.49
HG  -17.98  8.77
HG  -22.71  9.26
HG  -23.33  9.8
HG  -22.7   10.84
HG  -25.05  14.48
HG  -24.63  9.98
HG  -21.08  10.53
HG  -24.93  8.42
HG  -19.62  15.6
HG  -23.82  7.7
HG  -20.08  8.83
HG  -24.36  11.01
HG  -24.55  9.25
HG  -21.89  16.59
HG  -19 14.9
HG  -18.96  17.69
HG  -24.49  7.73
HG  -19.15  8.82
HG  -21.68  15.42
HG  -23.6   8.03
HG  -21.07  7.7
HG  -19.56  14.34
HG  -18.31  7.19
HG  -23.39  14.24
HG  -19.48  17.21
HG  -18.25  8.71
HG  -23.9   12.06
HG  -23.19  8.59
HG  -25.03  15.09
HG  -21.01  11.74
HG  -20.44  14.47
HG  -24.4   10.5
HG  -24.17  13.62
HG  -22.41  15.63
HG  -23.23  15.03
HG  -25.22  13.36
HG  -25.74  7.21
HG  -18.01  12.47
HG  -19.51  13.72
HG  -25 14.56
HG  -23.8   8.04
HG  -21.99  12.24
HG  -19.43  15.52
HG  -24.93  9.45
HG  -24.86  9.27
LB  -25.27  12.94
LB  -25.58  12.73
HG  -26.02  10.28
HG  -24.02  15.89
GB  -24.85  7.14
LB  -23.24  16.17

library(pillar)
library(rlang)
library (dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggstance)

    fnc = function(data, group, x, y, z, adj=1) {

      group=enquo(group)
      x = enquo(x)
      y = enquo(y)
      z = enquo(z)

      # Set size of whisker end caps
      wv = data %>% pull(!!y) %>% range %>% diff/100*adj
      wh = data %>% pull(!!x) %>% range %>% diff/100*adj

      # If grouping variable is numeric, turn it into a factor
      if(data %>% pull(!!group) %>% is.numeric) {
        data = data %>%
      mutate(!!quo_name(group) := factor(!!group))
  }

  # Generate column names for the x and y means that we'll calculate below
  xmean = paste0(quo_text(x), "_mean")
  ymean = paste0(quo_text(y), "_mean")
  zmean = paste0(quo_text(z), "_mean")

  left_join(data,
            data %>%
              group_by(!!group) %>%
              summarise_at(vars(!!x, !!y, !!z) funs(mean=mean))
  ) %>%
    ggplot(aes(colour=!!group)) +
    geom_point(aes(x=!!x, y=!!y, z=!!z), size=5) +
    theme_classic() +
    geom_point(aes(x=!!sym(xmean), y=!!sym(ymean), z=!!sym(zmean)), shape=18, size=3) +
    stat_summary(fun.data=mean_se, fun.args=list(mult=1.96),
                 aes(x=!!sym(xmean), y=!!y, z=!!z),
                 geom="errorbar", width=wh) +
    stat_summaryh(fun.data=mean_se_h, fun.args=list(mult=1.96),
                  aes(x=!!x, y=!!y, z=!!z, sym(ymean)),
                  geom="errorbarh", width=wv) 


}


##plot the ERROR BAR
fnc(data, Species, d13C.lin, d34S.lin) +

  theme(axis.text=element_text(size=12, face = "bold", colour = "black"),
        axis.title=element_text(size=17,face="bold", colour = "black")) +
  theme(legend.text=element_text(size=14, face = "bold", colour = "black")) +
  theme(legend.background = element_rect(fill="white",
                                         size=0.5, linetype="solid", 
                                         colour ="black")) +
  theme(legend.title = element_text(size = 14, face = "bold", colour = "black")) +
  labs(y = expression(delta^{34}*"S"*" (‰)"), x = expression(delta^{13}*"C"*" (‰)"))
```

This is the error message I receive:

> Error in is_call(expr, paren_sym) : 
>     argument "expr" is missing, with no default

As I say, any help greatly appreciated please.

Comment: Please include the code which produces this error message.

Comment: Hi - the code I used (unsuccessfully) is below the data.  Many thanks M.

Answer (score 0):

The error comes from the `z` argument which is not passed as argument in the function.

```
fnc <- function(data, group, x, y, adj=1) {

      group <- enquo(group)
      x <- enquo(x)
      y <- enquo(y)
      

      # Set size of whisker end caps
      wv <- data %>% 
               pull(!!y) %>%
               range %>% 
               diff/100*adj
      wh <- data %>% 
               pull(!!x) %>% 
               range %>%
               diff/100*adj
         # If grouping variable is numeric, turn it into a factor
         if(data %>% 
                  pull(!!group) %>%
                  is.numeric) {
           data <- data %>%
                      mutate(!!quo_name(group) := factor(!!group))
     }
     
  # Generate column names for the x and y means that we'll calculate below
  
   xmean <- str_c(as_name(x), "_mean")
   ymean <- str_c(as_name(y), "_mean")

  left_join(data,   
            data %>%
              group_by(!!group) %>%
              summarise_at(vars(!!x, !!y), list(mean = ~ mean(.))))  %>%
      ggplot(aes(colour=!!group)) +
      geom_point(aes(x=!!x, y=!!y), size=5) +
      theme_classic() +
      geom_point(aes(x=!!sym(xmean), y=!!sym(ymean)), shape=18, size=3) +
      stat_summary(fun.data=mean_se, fun.args=list(mult=1.96),
                   aes(x=!!sym(xmean), y=!!y),
                   geom="errorbar", width=wh)  +
      stat_summaryh(fun.data=mean_se_h, fun.args=list(mult=1.96),
                                aes(x=!!x, y = !!y),
                                geom="errorbarh", width=wv) 

  }
```

-testing

```
fnc(df1, Species, d13C.lin, d34S.lin)
```

[image]

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Species = c("GB", "HG", "HG", "HG", "HG", "HG", 
"HG", "HG", "HG", "HG", "HG", "HG", "HG", "HG", "HG", "GB", "GB", 
"LB", "LB", "LB", "LB", "LB", "LB", "HG", "HG", "HG", "HG", "HG", 
"HG", "HG", "HG", "HG", "HG", "HG", "HG", "HG", "HG", "HG", "HG", 
"HG", "HG", "HG", "HG", "HG", "HG", "HG", "HG", "HG", "HG", "HG", 
"HG", "HG", "HG", "HG", "HG", "HG", "HG", "HG", "HG", "HG", "HG", 
"HG", "HG", "HG", "HG", "HG", "HG", "HG", "HG", "HG", "HG", "HG", 
"LB", "LB", "HG", "HG", "GB", "LB"), d13C.lin = c(-20.1, -20.1, 
-19.51, -17.55, -23.72, -23.79, -18.09, -21.98, -18.6, -22.75, 
-21.7, -25, -17.61, -20.5, -18.14, -22.01, -19.62, -21.69, -25.56, 
-23.43, -22.92, -23.81, -25.42, -26.11, -20.61, -19.18, -19.76, 
-17.98, -22.71, -23.33, -22.7, -25.05, -24.63, -21.08, -24.93, 
-19.62, -23.82, -20.08, -24.36, -24.55, -21.89, -19, -18.96, 
-24.49, -19.15, -21.68, -23.6, -21.07, -19.56, -18.31, -23.39, 
-19.48, -18.25, -23.9, -23.19, -25.03, -21.01, -20.44, -24.4, 
-24.17, -22.41, -23.23, -25.22, -25.74, -18.01, -19.51, -25, 
-23.8, -21.99, -19.43, -24.93, -24.86, -25.27, -25.58, -26.02, 
-24.02, -24.85, -23.24), d34S.lin = c(8.09, 8.09, 9.46, 16.81, 
8.03, 9.02, 8.64, 10.95, 8.5, 10.9, 9.08, 7.23, 16.56, 10.17, 
15.4, 15.78, 12.62, 14.96, 8.4, 13.61, 12.68, 15.47, 8.63, 14.15, 
9.27, 15.67, 14.49, 8.77, 9.26, 9.8, 10.84, 14.48, 9.98, 10.53, 
8.42, 15.6, 7.7, 8.83, 11.01, 9.25, 16.59, 14.9, 17.69, 7.73, 
8.82, 15.42, 8.03, 7.7, 14.34, 7.19, 14.24, 17.21, 8.71, 12.06, 
8.59, 15.09, 11.74, 14.47, 10.5, 13.62, 15.63, 15.03, 13.36, 
7.21, 12.47, 13.72, 14.56, 8.04, 12.24, 15.52, 9.45, 9.27, 12.94, 
12.73, 10.28, 15.89, 7.14, 16.17)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, 
-78L))
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes I added the 'z' thinking (no doubt incorrectly) that this would constitute the third group. Clearly this isn't the case! Please see my edit to this question - I'm starting to think that producing mean +/- s.e. for GB (n = 4) is actually likely to be invalid.

Comment: Thanks. If the cause of the error was low n for GB, it is interesting that you've produced a plot! There should also be a horizontal line for the mean +/- s.e. for d13C.lin. I'm tempted not to proceed anyway, given the low n for GB, which I don't think is sufficient for a standard error value. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Mike_989  I didn't test the `stat_summaryh` earlier as I was concentrating on the error.  Updated the posst

Comment: I'm not aware of stat_summary() - thanks for mentioning! M.